# Runnig python from sublime text extremely slow

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm testing Sublime Text 2 with Python.
A simple hello python script takes multiple seconds.

```
print "Hello from Python"

Hello from Python
[Finished in 11.8s]
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the first run, since the second it's fast. Because it takes time to load python interpreter, parsing the byte-codes and actually running.

First:

```
Hello from Python
[Finished in 5.4s]
```

Second and later:

```
Hello from Python
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: That shouldn't take five whole seconds even the first time. Python does not take *that* long to start up. There aren't even any imports in that script.

Comment: it was not the second or the third run that ran fast, but after a couple of runs now is normal. Not exactly sure why.